# Prove the group is a direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-sum

Let $G$ be an abelian group of finite order $n = mk$ with gcd$(m,k) = 1$. For $r=m,k$, let $G(r) = \{g \in G: g^r = 1 \}$ . Prove that $G = G(m) \times G(k)$.

Comment: Welcome to this site! This site is for posting your mathematical questions to get answers, not for posting your mathematical tasks (or assignments) to have someone do them for you. What have you tried? What is it that you don't understand? Once this is clear to you, you can ask a precise question (notice that your post does not contain a question, just an "order" to perform a task).

Comment: It depends on what you can use.  Do you know yet the structure theorem for finite abelian groups?

Comment: Sorry guys, I am a graduate student who is studying for an algebra and linear algebra qualifying exam. I really just glossed over this problem and didn't really try it. However, the answer given below convinces me that this problem was not that difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not hard to show that $G(m)$ and $G(k)$ are subgroups and intersect each other trivially. We need to show then that $G(m)G(k)=G$. Suppose $g\in G$ is an element; then since $m$ and $k$ are relatively prime we have that there are integers $a,b$ such that $am+bk=1$. Then $g=g^{am}g^{bk}$, and $g^{am}\in G(k)$ and $g^{bk}\in G(m)$, so $G(m)G(k)=G$.